# Json response data fetch to html table

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

As i'm a new dev, I come with a problem .
I am fetching data from database using Ajax call. My response is like below

```
{
    "orderdetails":
    {
    "PROD_CODE":["017.601.104"],
    "PROD_NAME":["Super Cat Door With Chitkini (2.5 x 2.5)' - left"],
    "GROSS_RATE":["914"],
    "SALE_RATE":["800"],
    "PERSENT":["12.473"],
    "SALE_QNTY":["1"],
    "TOTAL_PRICE":["800"]
    }
}
```

I want to show this JSON response to a table like

```
<table class=" table table-hover table-condensed dtltable ">
    <tr>
    <th>Item code</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Gross Rate</th>
    <th>Sale Rate</th>
    <th>Percent</th>
    <th>Sasle qntity</th>
    <th>Total price</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

For that i'm trying the following code

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: './getOrderdtl.php',
                 data: {ordid: $text},
                success: function(data) {

                    alert(data.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                         var tr = $('<tr/>');
                    //   alert(data[PROD_CODE[i]]);

                        // Indexing into data.report for each td element
                        $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PROD_CODE+ "</td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PROD_NAME + "</td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td> " + data[i].GROSS_RATE + " </td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text' value=''>" + data[i].SALE_RATE + "</input> </td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PERSENT + "</td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text'>" + data[i].SALE_QNTY + "</input> </td>");
                        $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].TOTAL_PRICE + "</td>");
                        $('.dtltable').append(tr);

                     }
                },


        error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
            alert(xhr);
        }

            });
```

But the return is UNDEFINED , thats mean in every row of targeted table populated with 'undefind' text. Whats wrong with my code ? how do you get raid of this freaky problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add dataType: 'JSON' in your jQuery AjAX request and change data.length to data.orderdetails.length.

**Example:**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: './getOrderdtl.php',
             data: {ordid: $text},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                data = data.orderdetails;
                alert(data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                     var tr = $('<tr/>');
                //   alert(data[PROD_CODE[i]]);

                    // Indexing into data.report for each td element
                    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PROD_CODE+ "</td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PROD_NAME + "</td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td> " + data[i].GROSS_RATE + " </td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text' value=''>" + data[i].SALE_RATE + "</input> </td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].PERSENT + "</td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text'>" + data[i].SALE_QNTY + "</input> </td>");
                    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].TOTAL_PRICE + "</td>");
                    $('.dtltable').append(tr);

                 }
            },


    error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
        alert(xhr);
    }

        });
```

Comment: I've changed but no luck. when I change dataType: 'JSON', and alert (data.orderdetails.length) it says, "undefined" in Alert Message. And no data fetched in table !

Comment: How are you outputting result in php file? Are you properly encoding it using `json_encode`?

Comment: Do you mind sharing content of your getOrderdtl.php file?

Comment: Dear please check this url http://182.163.98.60:8070/ordercheck/getorderdtl.php directly from your browser. you will find the response

Comment: did you find my response file?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it seems fine to me. Also, I have checked and its working fine for me. For testing I used the following code: `$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getorderdtl.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    crossDomain : true,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response.orderdetails);
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Values are inside `orderdetails` object so your append lines shoud be :

```
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].orderdetails.PROD_CODE+ "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].orderdetails.PROD_NAME + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td> " + data[i].orderdetails.GROSS_RATE + " </td>");
    $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text' value=''>" + data[i].orderdetails.SALE_RATE + "</input> </td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].orderdetails.PERSENT + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td> <input type='text'>" + data[i].orderdetails.SALE_QNTY + "</input> </td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].orderdetails.TOTAL_PRICE + "</td>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am getting error as follow

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROD_CODE' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):136)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)